# When did PDO SQLite come into being?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

What is the first version of PHP that started supporting the [PDO_SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) driver? I know it was PHP 5 that brought PDO into the core so I'm assuming that PDO_SQLite must have been in version 5.0 also...

I want to know what requirements I'll need for a script using PDO_SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_SQLITE

First beta release: 2005-02-09
The latest PHP version at the time was 5.0.3 (see [here](http://php.net/releases/index.php))

Current stable release (1.0.1) needs PHP 5.0.3 or newer.